Application using springboot and jacoco plugin. Print success ratio during maven application build
enter image description here
Currently the application is printing code coverage when success ratio < expected ratio."Rule violation".I want to print success ratio for code coverage for the application during build process.
I tried to add the below code:
<version>3.0.0</version> <!-- Update version if needed -->
    <configuration>
     <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version> <!-- Update version if needed -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>print-coverage</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>echo</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>"Code Coverage Ratio: ${jacoco.line.covered}/${jacoco.line.total}"</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


Please show full pom file...it looks like wrong configuration which will never work...

@khmarbaise I am unable to add full file here

@SmitaKumari you just need to copy paste the whole pom file content instead of the snipped you already pasted

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
